# django cookiecutter compile sass in docker

Tags: django, docker, sass, cookiecutter-django

I am running [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) locally with docker. How do I compile the sass?

I run the app by doing `$ docker-compose --file local.yml up`. When I edit the source code template files the web app reflects those changes at http://localhost:8000

When I edit `static/sass/project.scss` the site does not get the new css rules.

I tried running `$ docker-compose --file local.yml run --rm npm install` but I get the message `ERROR: No such service: npm`.

Resources that might help:

1. https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/live-reloading-and-sass-compilation.html
2. https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html#building-running-production-stack

Answer (score 1):

The service name (from the docker-compose file is `node`.
The command should be `$ docker-compose --file local.yml run --rm node npm install`